# JMESPath to filter on object instead of array

Tags: json, github, graphql, filtering, jmespath

Sorry, I tried but simply cannot get my JMESPath filtering works to filter Github GraphQL for private repos.

Here is the Github GraphQL result I want to filter:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repositoryOwner": {
      "repositories": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "foo",
              "isFork": false,
              "isPrivate": true,
              "createdAt": "2019-04-25T20:31:07Z",
              "updatedAt": "2019-04-30T03:44:30Z",
              "primaryLanguage": {
                "primaryLanguage": "JavaScript"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "bar",
              "isFork": false,
              "isPrivate": true,
              "createdAt": "2019-04-25T01:26:31Z",
              "updatedAt": "2019-04-28T23:16:03Z",
              "primaryLanguage": {
                "primaryLanguage": "JavaScript"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "fur",
              "isFork": false,
              "isPrivate": false,
              "createdAt": "2019-04-25T02:46:28Z",
              "updatedAt": "2019-06-12T15:46:30Z",
              "primaryLanguage": {
                "primaryLanguage": "JavaScript"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "blog",
              "isFork": false,
              "isPrivate": false,
              "createdAt": "2013-03-17T13:37:44Z",
              "updatedAt": "2019-06-08T02:58:44Z",
              "primaryLanguage": null
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "blogs",
              "isFork": false,
              "isPrivate": true,
              "createdAt": "2015-12-06T03:52:14Z",
              "updatedAt": "2016-02-27T05:17:52Z",
              "primaryLanguage": {
                "primaryLanguage": "CSS"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried

```
data.repositoryOwner.repositories.edges.node[?isPrivate==`true`]
data.repositoryOwner.repositories.edges[].node[?isPrivate==`true`]
data.repositoryOwner.repositories.edges[].[node[?isPrivate==`true`]]
```

But none of them give me the list I want, as every single example from https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html is about filtering on array elements, whereas mine above is not.

Similar situation, for

`curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/events | jp "[?type=='IssuesEvent'].payload.{Title: issue.title, URL: issue.url, User: issue.user.login, Event: action}"`

How to further filter above on `payload.action=='created'` (in place without using pipes)?

***UPDATE2:***

The answer is,

`[?type=='IssueCommentEvent' && payload.action=='created'].payload.{Title: issue.title, URL: issue.url, User: issue.user.login, Event: action}`

and we'll get:

```json
[
  {
    "Title": "x/website: post https://go.dev/blog/tidy-web contains a broken link",
    "URL": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/issues/47975",
    "User": "ilikegolang",
    "Event": "created"
  },
  {
    "Title": "cmd/compile: pointer to concrete type doesn't satisfy generic type method set",
    "URL": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/issues/48512",
    "User": "DmitriyMV",
    "Event": "created"
  },
  {
    "Title": "How to solve this problem, run gomobile bind-target = android to report an error ",
    "URL": "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/issues/48510",
    "User": "ytxyyt",
    "Event": "created"
  },
. . .
]
```

Please help.

**UPDATE:**

I asked, *"as every single example from https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html is about filtering on array elements, whereas mine above is not"*, and got:

> In order to filter, you will need an array.

However, that's not what I'm expecting, as using the first one as the example, I'm expecting the filtered to be a JSON array:

```
[
      {
          "name": "foo",
          "isFork": false,
          "isPrivate": true,
          "createdAt": "2019-04-25T20:31:07Z",
          "updatedAt": "2019-04-30T03:44:30Z",
          "primaryLanguage": {
            "primaryLanguage": "JavaScript"
      },
      {
          "name": "bar",
          "isFork": false,
          "isPrivate": true,
          "createdAt": "2019-04-25T01:26:31Z",
          "updatedAt": "2019-04-28T23:16:03Z",
          "primaryLanguage": {
            "primaryLanguage": "JavaScript"
      },
      {
          "name": "blogs",
          "isFork": false,
          "isPrivate": true,
          "createdAt": "2015-12-06T03:52:14Z",
          "updatedAt": "2016-02-27T05:17:52Z",
          "primaryLanguage": {
            "primaryLanguage": "CSS"
      }
    ]
```

I can accept "no way" as the answer, but that seems to be a serious design flaw, as JsonPath can easily do that.

Comment: _"In order to filter, you will need an array"_, I know the root cause might be similar @β.εηοιτ.βε, but my asking is different from that answer. I've made it clearer in OP. So the answer to my question seems to be a "NO"?

Comment: Oh, that wasn’t clear without the expected result. That’s a bit clearer now. No, what you expect here is totally doable, since you "just" want to filter on the `edges` array. I’ll give it a try later today if you don’t have an answer by then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filtering have to happen on the `edges` array, still, the property you evaluate can be nested deeper in the object.
So you can perfectly have a condition like `` node.isPrivate == `true` ``, or even simpler, since `node.isPrivate` is already a boolean, a condition that would simply read `node.isPrivate`.

Given the query:

```
data.repositoryOwner.repositories.edges[?node.isPrivate].node
```

We end up with the expect JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "isFork": false,
    "isPrivate": true,
    "createdAt": "2019-04-25T20:31:07Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-04-30T03:44:30Z",
    "primaryLanguage": {
      "primaryLanguage": "JavaScript"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "bar",
    "isFork": false,
    "isPrivate": true,
    "createdAt": "2019-04-25T01:26:31Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-04-28T23:16:03Z",
    "primaryLanguage": {
      "primaryLanguage": "JavaScript"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "blogs",
    "isFork": false,
    "isPrivate": true,
    "createdAt": "2015-12-06T03:52:14Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-02-27T05:17:52Z",
    "primaryLanguage": {
      "primaryLanguage": "CSS"
    }
  }
]
```